# Linq Windows Form C# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm a student doing an assignment which is an appointment system, I'm using Management Studio for the database, I detached it and linked Visual Studio with the .mdf file.

I can't find where the error is and never solved this type of error before.

Code:

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        public frmAccountCreation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = txtEmail.ToString();
        string fullname = txtFullname.ToString();
        string username = txtUsername.ToString();
        string password = txtPassword.ToString();
        int userlevel;
        string contactnumber =txtContactNumber.ToString();
        if(ckbAdmin.Checked)
        {
            userlevel = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            userlevel = 0;
        }

        tblUserAccount account = new tblUserAccount
        {
            Username = username,
            Passcode = password,
            UserPrivelage = userlevel
        };

        tblVet vet = new tblVet
        {
            Email = email,
            FullName = fullname,
            ContactNumber = contactnumber
        };

        db.tblUserAccounts.InsertOnSubmit(account);
        db.tblVets.InsertOnSubmit(vet);
        db.SubmitChanges();//Error Is here
    }
}
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL

Comment: We'll need more information. The SqlException object that's thrown will have more information, like an error message.

Comment: And check also the inner exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling everything related to visual studio community 2015 and my antivirus avg after i reinstalled everything worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this line:

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext("C:\\Users\\Luke\\Desktop\\OOP Assignment\\OOP_Database.mdf");
```

You are trying to open the MDF file directly. You cannot do that. You need a running SQL server instance (which can be on your development machine, like SQL Express), and you will need a connection string to connect to that server.

Comment: so you mean i will need to have management studio open whit visual and what would the connection string be in this case ?

Comment: would this be the connection string ? Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OOP_Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Comment: If you have LocalDB installed, then that would likely be the connection string.

Comment: i edited the code above it still has the same output unfortunately the same error is given

Comment: Did you install LocalDB?

Comment: if you need further code ecc send me an email and il send everything i have done email: luke.scicluna@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: The path in your revised question is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\", but you used to have "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\OOP Assignment". Where is your MDF file?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\" is where management studio stores the mdf files

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with LocalDB, so I've just be going from what I'm reading online. But you can check common things, like does the account the app is running with have access to that mdf file?

Answer (score -1):

It seems your `SQL Server Service` is not running.

In Windows, search for "Services" and there should be a Windows application with the same name.

In the application keep scrolling untill you find "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" and make sure it's running.